Is it possible to go to a new View from a button click, without using the NavigationStack(view)?
If for whatever reason I didn't wish to use NavigationStack or NavigationView, is it possible to call a new view from a button click?
I tried the code below, however the furthest I can get is getting the returned view, however I don't know how to call it.

"Result of call to 'getView(view:)' is unused"

import SwiftUI

struct BasicButton: View {
    var buttonLabel = "Create User"
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            getView(view: "CreateUser")
            
        } label: {
            Text(buttonLabel)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .font(.title2)
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 55)
        .background(.blue)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

@ViewBuilder func getView(view: String) -> any View {
    switch view {
    case "CreateUser":
        CreateUser()
    default:
        EmptyView()
    }
}

struct CreateUser: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}



#Preview {
    BasicButton()
}

#Preview {
    CreateUser()
}


You can't return a View inside a Button's action closure. Instead, you should change some state that is then reflected in the view hierarchy.
Here's an example:
enum Page {
    case button
    case createUser
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var page: Page = .button
    
    var body: some View {
        switch page {
        case .button:
            BasicButton(page: $page)
        case .createUser:
            CreateUser()
        }
    }
}

struct BasicButton: View {
    @Binding var page: Page
    
    private static let buttonLabel = "Create User"
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            page = .createUser
        } label: {
            Text(Self.buttonLabel)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .font(.title2)
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 55)
        .background(.blue)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

struct CreateUser: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}

Note that if you did want to use a ViewBuilder at some point, like in your getView function, you'd want to return some View, not any View

Crazy follow up question, as I am trying to implement your suggestion.  IN the above example, when page changes, does CreateUser call a new View? Erasing the current one?

Either BasicButton or CreateUser is rendered, depending on what page is. If you want to think about that as "erasing" the previous one, you could, but that's not the mental model I use.

But when going back and forth between the two, does the previous view get erased?  Am confused because calling Text() and CustomView() are basically the same, no?

Again, I'm not sure "erased" is the right verb. It is no longer in the view hierarchy and is thus not rendered. If you want to think about that as "erased", that's fine.

I'm going to report this as a new question, just to make sure I'm not doing, or more precisely...misunderstanding something.  Thanks for all your help so far.
